# Check empty rows query

Tags: php, mysqli

In fact I am working on a small PHP script but I am facing a problem right now.The problem is that i want to check if my query return records this is my mysqli query:

```
    $sql = "select * from specs where btitleid=$id and phoneid=$aydi"
    $check = $conn->query($sql)
    while($row = $check->fetch_assoc()) {$tocheck = $row['content'];}
```

I don't want to check the number of rows of this query to see if it is null.I want to check if all `$row['content']` are empty.

Comment: Use `if` condition then.

Comment: @Fred-ii- How can i use If with While ?

Comment: Answer's been given below; my thoughts exactly.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Please check the comment on the answer below. Thank you.

Comment: To check if they're all empty you would have to issue a query just for that purpose. Unless you want to return rows where the column is not empty.

Comment: @JayBlanchard It's ok can you please tell me how to do exactly this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this:

```
$sql = "select * from specs where btitleid=$id and phoneid=$aydi";
$check = $conn->query($sql);

$contentAllEmpty = true;
while ($row = $check->fetch_assoc()) {
    if (strlen($row['content']) > 0) {
        $contentAllEmpty = false;
    }
}

if ($contentAllEmpty) {
    //do something
}
```

Comment: Your code won't work in my case, your code will check if there is at least one empty $row['content'], in my case i want to check if they are all empty. Thank you for your help.

Comment: I've updated it so it checks if all the rows are empty.

Answer (score 0):

use `==`

```
while ($row = $check->fetch_assoc()) {
if ($row['content'] == '') {
    ... code here
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To get back only records where the content column is not empty -

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `specs` WHERE `btitleid` = $id AND `phoneid` = $aydi AND (`content` IS NOT NULL OR `content` != '') ";
```

Comment: Check peter's answer it's working perfectly, Thank you so much for your help.